# PHP withdrawing attributes from database using explode

Tags: php, mysql, attributes, explode

I'm searching the best way to withdraw some data from my MySQL field by I fail everytime. So here I come...

I got some data in my db which looks following: "attribute1=0::attribute2=1::attribute3=5 .. etc.".

Now I need to get that data so I can use it like this:

```
foreach($xxx as $attributeName => $attributeValue)
echo $attributeName . ' = ' . $attributeValue;
```

So the above will print smg like;

attribute1 = 0
attribute2 = 1
... etc.

Hope you understand and help me out with this. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: So you want to know how to retrieve the data from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$final = array();
$str =  "attribute1=0::attribute2=1::attribute3=5";
$pairs = explode('::', $str);

foreach ($pairs as $pair)
{
    $keyValue = explode('=', $pair);
    $final[$keyValue[0]] = $keyValue[1];

}

print_r($final);
```

Answer (score 1):

So here is what you do:

```
$data = 'attribute1=0::attribute2=1::attribute3=5';

$data_tree = explode("::", $data);
foreach($data_tree as $node)
{
    list($field,$value) = explode('=',$node);
    echo $field.' : '.$value.'<br/>';
}
```

it will print:

> ```
> attribute1 : 0
> attribute2 : 1
> attribute3 : 5
> ```

#### Good Luck!